# Locale on a rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, locale

So I have translated all my pages using the I18n part of rails. My problem is that when I change page, the language resorts back to default. I have the following in my routes.

```
Games::Application.routes.draw do
  get "game_interest/new"
  get "rules/index"
  get "feedback/index"
  get "help/index"

  get "log_in"  => "sessions#new",     :as => "log_in"
  get "log_out" => "sessions#destroy", :as => "log_out"
  get "sign_up" => "users#new",        :as => "sign_up"

  get "home/index"
  get "about/index"

  resources :feedbacks
  resources :password_resets
  resources :contact_messages
  resources :wishlists
  resources :searches
  resources :help  
  resources :users
  resources :sessions

  resources :games do
    post 'email',     :on => :member
    post 'gensearch', :on => :member
    post 'consearch', :on => :member
  end

  root :to => 'home#index'
end
```

I tried rapping the following in a scope "(:locale)" do but I then get missing controller errors. any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use a similar pattern to the one you've tried (i.e. wrapping the routes in `scope (:locale) do ... end` and it works fine with us. You might need to add explicit controllers and actions to your get routes to get rid of the missing controller errors. i.e.

```
get "game_interest/new" => 'controller#action'
get "rules/index" => 'controller#action'
# etc, etc
```

I'd suggest having a play with using the scope and explicit mapping of routes to actions and testing using `rake routes`